# Closed duplicates that may need some moderator attention

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

There's a process called the Roomba that automatically deletes posts that meet [certain criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675). Because duplicates often help others locate answers to the same question they are excluded, however a while back I spotted the following question that is no longer useful in my opinion:

[motorola smbobol scanner secerts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97637/motorola-smbobol-scanner-secerts)

It hasn't received any answers and would have been deleted long ago if it had been closed as off-topic the same as the duplicate from the same user. Most users that click the duplicate link will see "removed for reasons of moderation" and for 10k users there's not much of interest to see. It made me wonder if there were many more and there are currently 19 questions where the duplicate target as been deleted:

[Find duplicates of deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/229621/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts)

I don't think all should be deleted for example the following and others with decent answers probably just needs re-opening (or closing for another reason) to get rid of the deleted duplicate link:

[How to select value of resistor to dicharge a capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126908/how-to-select-value-of-resistor-to-dicharge-a-capacitor)

Anyway I just thought I'd bring it up for discussion and see if any moderators thought it was worth cleaning them up, they just look like dead links for most users. I put in a related [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239124/change-to-operation-of-roomba-when-deleting-duplicates) on Meta.SE to handle them automatically that doesn't seem to have received any objections but not too much attention either.